# SQL select Split column and then find in other split select

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have a SQL Server table that one column has comma separated values:

```
12323,234322,1112,99323.....
```

And I have a parameter `@values nvarchar(500)` that will also have comma separated values.

In my query I need to check if anything from the parameter exists in my table field.

Something like this>

```
...
WHERE 
(@values = '' OR select s from dbo.Split(',',t.Data) in ( select s from dbo.Split(',',@values )))
```

Of course the above gives me errors.

> Any clue?

Comment: Take a peek at CROSS APPLY, or post a more robust sample for more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Join both tables that you got out of the split

```
SELECT *
...
FROM (SELECT s FROM dbo.Split(',',t.Data)) X
INNER JOIN (SELECT s FROM dbo.Split(',',@values)) Y
ON X.s = Y.s
...
```

Comment: Thats a totally independant select I need it in my where statement

Answer (score 0):

[EXISTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188336.aspx) is your friend here.

```
 WHERE 
(@values = '' OR EXISTS (select a.value from string_split(t.Data, ',') a inner join ( select value from string_split(@values, ',')) b ON a.value = b.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code it may helps you

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #Temp

Declare @SearchVariable varchar(1000)='12323,234322,1112,99323,22222,4545,656565,8989,1111,22222'--Varibale Contains these values to search

CREATE TABLE #Temp (CommaValue Varchar(100))-- This is the table having comma separted value columns
INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT '12323,234322,1112,99323' Union all
SELECT '12323,656565,1112,4545'

Declare @VariableSearch TABLE (ValueName varchar(1000))
Insert into @VariableSearch

SELECT @SearchVariable
;With cte
AS
(
SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS TablesData
            FROM (
                SELECT CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(CommaValue, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS TablesData
                FROM #Temp
                ) AS A
            CROSS APPLY TablesData.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
)
SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER()Over(Order by (SELECT 1)) AS Rno, * from cte C Inner join
(
SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS VariableSeachData
            FROM (
                SELECT CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(ValueName, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS VariableSeachData
                FROM @VariableSearch
                ) AS A
            CROSS APPLY VariableSeachData.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
            )DT
            On  C.TablesData=DT.VariableSeachData
```

OutPut

```
Rno TablesData  VariableSeachData
---------------------------------
1       1112            1112
2       1112            1112
3       12323           12323
4       12323           12323
5       234322          234322
6       4545            4545
7       656565          656565
8       99323           99323
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, but maybe this can give you an idea.

using [Outer Apply](https://sqlwithmanoj.com/tag/outer-apply/) and [EXISTS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp) operator.

```
SELECT x.value
    FROM    Table T
            OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    value
                          FROM      dbo.Split(t.data)
                        ) X
    WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                         FROM   dbo.Split(@values) S
                         WHERE  s.value = x.value )
```